# gzip compression showing off even though enabled

Tags: nginx

I'm unsure as to why gzip it showing as failed on both webpagetest and gtmetrix when in my nginx config I have it enabled.

I'm currently running `nginx version: nginx/1.10.1`

Here is my current nginx config

```
# HTTPS
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    root /home/www/youtstream;
    server_name dev.yout.com
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    access_log  off;
    error_log off;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /srv/dehydrated/certs/dev.yout.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /srv/dehydrated/certs/dev.yout.com/privkey.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /static {
        alias  /home/www/youtstream/static/;
    }
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|mp4|woff2)$ {
        expires           max;
    }
```

Here is the results of [webpagetest](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/170105_1C_2T86/1/performance_optimization/#compress_text) and [gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/dev.yout.com/gzAX1qcC)

Comment: Mime type of `js` is `application/javascript` (you can find it in `/etc/nginx/mime.types`). This mime does not included in `gzip_types` directive.

Comment: @DmitryMiksIr that fixed it! If you want to place it as a answer I will accept